# %OSPF-4-ERRRCV: Received invalid packet: mismatch area ID, from backbone area must be virtual-link

Tags: cisco, ospf, packet-tracer

I have a topology like this:

[image]

this Router0-1's Gig0/0/0 ip: `10.0.12.1/24`, 
the  Router0-2's Gig0/0/0 ip: `10.0.12.2/24`, Gig0/0/1 ip: `10.0.23.2/24`, 
this Router0-3's Gig0/0/0 ip: `10.0.23.3/24`,

at first, all the router interfaces are announced into the Area 0.

now, I announced the Router0-3's Gig0/0/0 and Router0-2's Gig0/0/1 to the Area1, but the Router0-2 get bellow logs:

```
00:57:06: %OSPF-4-ERRRCV: Received invalid packet: mismatch area ID, from backbone area must be virtual-link but not found from 10.0.23.2, GigabitEthernet0/0/1

00:57:16: %OSPF-4-ERRRCV: Received invalid packet: mismatch area ID, from backbone area must be virtual-link but not found from 10.0.23.2, GigabitEthernet0/0/1

00:57:26: %OSPF-4-ERRRCV: Received invalid packet: mismatch area ID, from backbone area must be virtual-link but not found from 10.0.23.2, GigabitEthernet0/0/1

00:57:36: %OSPF-4-ERRRCV: Received invalid packet: mismatch area ID, from backbone area must be virtual-link but not found from 10.0.23.2, GigabitEthernet0/0/1
```

....

I have tried clear ospf prgress in Router0-3, still this issue.

in the Router0-1 ospf database:

```
Router1>show ip ospf database 
            OSPF Router with ID (1.1.1.1) (Process ID 1)

                Router Link States (Area 0)

Link ID         ADV Router      Age         Seq#       Checksum Link count
3.3.3.3         3.3.3.3         1703        0x80000002 0x00fef4 1
1.1.1.1         1.1.1.1         1034        0x80000008 0x0071a5 1
2.2.2.2         2.2.2.2         1034        0x80000009 0x0034d7 1

                Net Link States (Area 0)
Link ID         ADV Router      Age         Seq#       Checksum
10.0.23.3       3.3.3.3         1703        0x80000001 0x004c5f
10.0.12.2       2.2.2.2         1034        0x80000002 0x00bd6e

                Summary Net Link States (Area 0)
Link ID         ADV Router      Age         Seq#       Checksum
10.0.23.0       2.2.2.2         1529        0x80000001 0x00d65e
3.3.3.3         2.2.2.2         497         0x80000005 0x00ce76
```

in the Router0-2 ospf database:

```
Router2#show ip ospf database 
            OSPF Router with ID (2.2.2.2) (Process ID 1)

                Router Link States (Area 0)

Link ID         ADV Router      Age         Seq#       Checksum Link count
1.1.1.1         1.1.1.1         973         0x80000008 0x0071a5 1
3.3.3.3         3.3.3.3         1642        0x80000002 0x00fef4 1
2.2.2.2         2.2.2.2         973         0x80000009 0x0034d7 1

                Net Link States (Area 0)
Link ID         ADV Router      Age         Seq#       Checksum
10.0.23.3       3.3.3.3         1642        0x80000001 0x004c5f
10.0.12.2       2.2.2.2         973         0x80000002 0x00bd6e

                Summary Net Link States (Area 0)
Link ID         ADV Router      Age         Seq#       Checksum
10.0.23.0       2.2.2.2         1468        0x80000001 0x00d65e
3.3.3.3         2.2.2.2         436         0x80000005 0x00ce76

                Router Link States (Area 1)

Link ID         ADV Router      Age         Seq#       Checksum Link count
2.2.2.2         2.2.2.2         446         0x8000000e 0x0027c8 1
3.3.3.3         3.3.3.3         446         0x80000009 0x00745b 2

                Net Link States (Area 1)
Link ID         ADV Router      Age         Seq#       Checksum
10.0.23.3       3.3.3.3         446         0x80000003 0x004ec4

                Summary Net Link States (Area 1)
Link ID         ADV Router      Age         Seq#       Checksum
10.0.12.0       2.2.2.2         1475        0x80000001 0x0050ef
```

in the Router0-3 ospf database:

```
Router3#show  ip ospf database 
            OSPF Router with ID (3.3.3.3) (Process ID 1)

                Router Link States (Area 1)

Link ID         ADV Router      Age         Seq#       Checksum Link count
2.2.2.2         2.2.2.2         536         0x8000000e 0x0027c8 1
3.3.3.3         3.3.3.3         536         0x80000009 0x00745b 2

                Net Link States (Area 1)
Link ID         ADV Router      Age         Seq#       Checksum
10.0.23.3       3.3.3.3         536         0x80000003 0x004ec4

                Summary Net Link States (Area 1)
Link ID         ADV Router      Age         Seq#       Checksum
10.0.12.0       2.2.2.2         1565        0x80000001 0x0050ef
```

Comment: could you please include config for routers? especially router 0-3

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your post experiment, when I in one area to assign R3's interface to Area1, the R2 will get this Error Receive logs.

But if you in R3 `no router ospf 1`, then launch a new OSPF process, and add the interface to Area 1 there will not get this fault.

and then show the Router2's OSPF database, there shows flawlessly.

```
Router2#show ip ospf database 
            OSPF Router with ID (2.2.2.2) (Process ID 1)

                Router Link States (Area 0)

Link ID         ADV Router      Age         Seq#       Checksum Link count
2.2.2.2         2.2.2.2         370         0x80000003 0x0048b0 2
1.1.1.1         1.1.1.1         370         0x80000003 0x0055b1 2

                Net Link States (Area 0)
Link ID         ADV Router      Age         Seq#       Checksum
10.0.12.2       2.2.2.2         370         0x80000001 0x002f8b

                Summary Net Link States (Area 0)
Link ID         ADV Router      Age         Seq#       Checksum
10.0.23.0       2.2.2.2         365         0x80000001 0x00d65e

                Router Link States (Area 1)

Link ID         ADV Router      Age         Seq#       Checksum Link count
3.3.3.3         3.3.3.3         375         0x80000003 0x00fef2 1
2.2.2.2         2.2.2.2         275         0x80000005 0x0039bf 1

                Net Link States (Area 1)
Link ID         ADV Router      Age         Seq#       Checksum
10.0.23.3       3.3.3.3         275         0x80000002 0x00a032

                Summary Net Link States (Area 1)
Link ID         ADV Router      Age         Seq#       Checksum
3.3.3.3         3.3.3.3         370         0x80000001 0x00ae97
2.2.2.2         2.2.2.2         365         0x80000001 0x00fa53
10.0.12.0       2.2.2.2         365         0x80000002 0x004ef0
1.1.1.1         2.2.2.2         360         0x80000003 0x002f20
```